# How Nodes are pointed/referenced in linkedlist

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I feel really confused about how nodes are referenced to each other in linkedlist.
Supposed we have code like this:

`NodeA: 1->2->3;
  NodeB: 6->7->8;
  ListNode NodeC = NodeA;
IF WE DO:
  NodeC.next = NodeB;// NodeC becomes 1->6->7->8, NodeA also changed to 1->6->7->8, why?
OR WE DO:
  NodeC = NodeB;//this will only change NodeC, but NodeA stay the origin, why?`

When we set two nodes are ponitning to the same, and if we change one node to point different next, the another one also get changed. **However**, if we only say NodeC = NodeB, it seems like there is nothing changed on NodeA. I have been struggling this for 
few days, could anyone explain how this work? really appreciate !

Comment: NodeC.next = NodeB should make NodeC and NodeA 1->6->7->8 otherwise this notation does not make sense to me either

Comment: opps, you were absolutely right, NodeC.nexr = NodeB, is cutting the reference and link it to NodeB! thanks for clarfication!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `NodeA: 1->2->3;`, there are 3 nodes being referenced, and 1 variable:

```
// These are the nodes. They don't have names, I'm just calling them NodeX, where X is a number.
Node1
  value = 1
  next = Node2
Node2
  value = 2
  next = Node3
Node3
  value = 3
  next = null
// This is the variable
NodeA = Node1
```

Then, `NodeB: 6->7->8;` refers to another set of nodes, `Node6, Node7, Node8`, and one variable `NodeB = Node6`.

When you do `NodeC = NodeA`, now there are two variables, each referencing `Node1`. So `NodeC = NodeA = 1->2->3`. Hopefully this makes sense so far.

When you do `NodeC.next = NodeB`, we're saying, for the node referenced by variable `NodeC` (which is `Node1`), update its `next` member to whatever is referenced by variable `NodeB` (which is `Node6`).

So

```
NodeC = NodeA = Node1 // Variables
NodeB = Node6
Node1
  value = 1
  next = Node6
```

So `NodeC = 1->6->7->8`. And since `NodeA` also refers to the same node that `NodeC` does, `NodeA also = 1->6->7->8`.

When you do `NodeC = NodeB`, `NodeC` now references `Node6`, and `NodeA` continues to reference `Node1`, so changes to `NodeC` don't affect `NodeA`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation, so if we change NodeC.next, the other nodes that pointing to NodeC will also change, because NodeC.next is not changing the value of NodeC itself, but changing the mapping relationship! Is my understanding right?  Really appreciate!